# Get picklist value in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I am using two custom object Parent (Part )and Child (Material) in visualforce page now my requirement is that i want to get Material Name in one picklist and also want to show its related machine name (which is a field on other custom object) in another picklist. i am using below code but its not working please help me to fix out this issue.

Here is my code

**Visualforce page:**

Material Names

```
     <apex:selectList value="{!selectedPartId}" size="1">                                 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MaterialNames}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="a"/>
     </apex:selectList>
```

Machine Names

```
         <apex:selectList value="{!selectedMaterialId}" size="1"  id="a">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!MachineNames}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="b"/> 
         </apex:selectList>
```

**Apex class:**

```
           public List<SelectOption> getMaterialNames() {
                  List<SelectOption> materialOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                  materialOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
                  for( Part__c pc : [select Id,name,Material__c from Part__c ] ) {
                          materialOptions.add( new SelectOption(part.id,part.Material__c));
                  }
                 return materialOptions;
           }

           public List<SelectOption> getMachineNames() {
                  System.debug('Entered ContactNames account id...........'+selectedPartId );
                  List<SelectOption> machineOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                    if(selectedPartId != null)
                    {     
                       for( Machine__c machine : [select Id,name from Machine__c where id=:selectedPartId ] ) {
                          machineOptions.add( new SelectOption(machine.Id,machine.name));
                       }
                    }                  
                    else
                    {
                        machineOptions.add( new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
                    }
                 return machineOptions;
           }
```

Comment: Don't you have any `action` on your `<apex:actionSupport>` ?

Comment: yes i am using action support there but there is some problem in soql query not able to fitech material name and its related machine name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need following corrections. First in first for loop replace `part.id,part.Material__c` with `pc.id,pc.Material__c`.

Your code

```
  for( Part__c pc : [select Id,name,Material__c from Part__c ] ) {
          materialOptions.add( new SelectOption(part.id,part.Material__c));
  }
```

Should be

```
  for( Part__c pc : [select Id,name,Material__c from Part__c ] ) {
          materialOptions.add( new SelectOption(pc.id,pc.Material__c));
  }
```

Second correction is -- In the below query I think you have to user partid in where clause. something like `select Id,name from Machine__c where partid__c=:selectedPartId` depending upon your field name.

```
   for( Machine__c machine : [select Id,name from Machine__c where id=:selectedPartId ] ) {
      machineOptions.add( new SelectOption(machine.Id,machine.name));
   }
```

Comment: After changes It is not showing material name in picklist it only show part name.

Comment: Can you post your updated code? Another thing you should avoid [Avoid SOQL Queries Inside FOR Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops).

Answer (score 0):

Your query on machine should filter for Part instead of Id

```
for( Machine__c machine : [select Id,name from Machine__c where PartId=:selectedPartId ] ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a problem in the rerender engine. Try this

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedPartId}" size="1">                                 
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!MaterialNames}"/>
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="materials"/>
     </apex:selectList>


<apex:outputPanel id="materials" layout="block">
    <apex:selectList value="{!selectedMaterialId}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!MachineNames}"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="nexPanel"/> 
         </apex:selectList>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

My Updated code:

```
public List<SelectOption> getMaterialNames() {
                      List<SelectOption> materialOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                      materialOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
                      for( Part__c pc : [select Id,name,Material__c from Part__c ] ) {
                              materialOptions.add( new SelectOption(pc.Id,pc.name));

                      }
                     return materialOptions;
                    // System.debug('value of Material__c'+Material__c);
                    // System.debug('value of pc'+pc);
               }

               public List<SelectOption> getMachineNames() {
                      System.debug('Entered ContactNames account id...........'+selectedPartId );
                      List<SelectOption> machineOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                        if(selectedPartId != null)
                        {     
                           for( Machine__c machine : [select Id,name,Part__c from Machine__c where Id=:selectedPartId ] ) {
                              machineOptions.add( new SelectOption(machine.Id,machine.name));
                             // System.debug('value of machine'+machine);
                           }
                        }                  
                        else
                        {
                            machineOptions.add( new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
                        }
                     return machineOptions;
               }
```